# Dart constructor initialization order

Tags: dart

```
class Base {
  num b;
  Base() {
    print("in Base");
  }

  Base.initB(b) {
    b = b;
    print("in Base.initB");
  }
}

class Point extends Base {
  num x;
  num y;
  final num f;

  Point(this.x, int y, smth, b): f=smth, super.initB(b) {
    print(this.x);
    this.y = y;
  }
}

main() {
  var a = new Point(1, 2, 3, 4); 
  // output:
  // in Base initB
  // 1
}
```

I'm learning Dart but found the documentation obscure. I want to know the initialization order of instance variables. There are two questions:

1. From my understanding, the initialization order is `x, f -> b -> y`, is it correct?
2. `x` and `f`, which is first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an order defined between `x` and `f` and if it were, it wouldn't matter. You can't access `x` or `f` from anywhere until after `suber.initB(b)` completed and the constructor body of `Point` started to be executed.

Besides that the order you derived is correct.

Answer (score 4):

I can understand that the documentation seems obscure. I believe it's completely broken for object initialization, and it's on the ["to-fix" list](https://dartbug.com/26765) (UPDATE: And that has changed. The specification should now be "more correct" around object initialization.)

In practice, the *evaluation order* of the initializer list is left-to-right. You can see that by having side-effects in initializer expressions.

The call to the super constructor happens either at the end (in the VM), or at the point where the super-call occurs (in Dart2JS). For that reason, you are recommended to always put the super-call last, and that's likely to be required in a later version of Dart. There is no advantage to putting it earlier.

After all initializer lists have been executed, and all initializing formals (like `this.x` above) have been processed, the object is considered initialized, and then the constructor bodies are executed in super-class first order with access to the new object as `this`.

When the actual object field is set is undefined. You only ever see the object after all fields are initialized. It's a perfectly valid implementation strategy to put all the values on the stack when evaluating the initializer lists, then allocate the object just before entering the first constructor body.

Here is [an example](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/2d7d300f28c12a244f2680b37a8a0e91) that shows evaluation order.